# autofmt_xdate() using backend_agg

Tags: python, pandas

I'm using python pandas on a headless server to generate graphs which are subsequently served up on a web page.  Because of the limitations, I can't use the well-written .plot() functionality in pandas (which would automatically handle my formatting mess), and instead I must create the graph (.png file) in a way that doesn't create a new window.

Code below does everything I need, but I'm stumped on where/how to call autofmt_xdate.  Run the code below and notice the x-axis date formatting mess.  Any help is appreciated, and apologies for any formatting errors in posting this.

My goal is to have the x-axis dates rotated 30 degrees or so.

```
#! /usr/bin/python
from matplotlib.backends.backend_agg import FigureCanvasAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
rng = pd.date_range( '1/1/2011', periods=20, )
ts = pd.Series(np.random.randn(len(rng)), index=rng)
fig = Figure()
canvas = FigureCanvas(fig)
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.plot_date(ts.index, ts, '-')
#ax.autofmt_xdate(rotation=30)  # this doesn't work.  Help!
canvas.print_png('test.png')
```

Comment: `autofmt_xdate()` has to be called on the figure not axis: `fig.autofmt_xdate()` (the rotation is already included)